# Can't install jQuery File Upload in expressjs

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, jquery-file-upload

I am newbie in nodejs.
When I am going to install blueimp-file-upload-expressjs the following error is coming.

```
D:\WorkShop\Express\zipzap>npm install blueimp-file-upload-expressjs --save
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package is discontinued. Use lodash@^4.0.0.

> lwip@0.0.6 install D:\WorkShop\Express\zipzap\node_modules\lwip
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\WorkShop\Express\zipzap\node_modules\lwip>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:454:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:480:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:114:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\WorkShop\Express\zipzap\node_modules\lwip
gyp ERR! node -v v7.7.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
gyp ERR! not ok
zipzap@0.0.0 D:\WorkShop\Express\zipzap
+-- async@0.9.2  extraneous
+-- aws-sdk@2.28.0  extraneous
+-- formidable@1.1.1  extraneous
`-- mkdirp@0.5.0  extraneous

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "blueimp-file-upload-expressjs" "--save"
npm ERR! node v7.7.2
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! lwip@0.0.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the lwip@0.0.6 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the lwip package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs lwip
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls lwip
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\WorkShop\Express\zipzap\npm-debug.log

D:\WorkShop\Express\zipzap>
```

How to install it and use this plugins? Also can't understand what is the actual error.
I am working on nodejs. then why is it asking for python path??

Comment: I can suggest two options: first downgrade your node to 6 and test again, and second: possible upgrade node-gyp@latest and check again, see this https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip/issues/206

Answer (score 0):

> @Dipankar Naskar: then why is it asking for python path??

Because Node.js is built with [GYP](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/) — cross-platform built tool written in Python. Also some other build steps are implemented in Python. So Python is required for building node from source.

> @Dipankar Naskar: How to install it and use this plugins?

It's solution for the almost case.

The config steps with **Node.js** should now be as follows:

Install [VC++ Build Tools Technical Preview](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools), choose *Custom Install*, and select both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 SDKs.

> [Windows 7 only] requires [.NET Framework 4.5.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40773)

Install Python 2.7 or 3.6, and add it to your `PATH`, `npm config set python python2.7`

Launch cmd, `npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global` (this is instead of `npm install [package name] --msvs_version=2015` every time.)

*SO MUCH* `npm install`

Note: with your problem, you only install Python, add it to your `PATH`, `npm config set python python2.7`.